# Please reopen this question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Please reopen this question:

[Which (South) East-Asian contries are the cleanest?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14181/which-south-east-asian-contries-are-the-cleanest)

A user said he created an excellent answer just before it was closed, so he cannot post it.

Answer (score 7):

Your question was closed as not constructive. You should edit it and then flag to reopen.
But the fact that a user has an answer is not a reason to reopen your question